# Calculating coordinates. Google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

I have some number of distance parts

```
int[] parts = [1823, 344, 2345, 1022, 2387, ...]; //in meters
```

I can calculate end/start location coordinates of every part in array. For that I use random bearing

```
int bearingRnd = new Random().nextInt(360);
```

and this formula

```
double dkm = parts[j]/1000.0;
double dist = dkm/6371.0;
double bearing = Math.toRadians(bearingRnd);
double firstLatitude = Math.toRadians(currentLat);
double firstLongitude = Math.toRadians(currentLng);

double secondLatitude = Math.asin(Math.sin(firstLatitude) * Math.cos(dist) + Math.cos(firstLatitude) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(bearing));
double a = Math.atan2(Math.sin(bearing) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(firstLatitude), Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(firstLatitude) * Math.sin(secondLatitude));
double secondLongitude = firstLongitude + a;
       secondLongitude = (secondLongitude + 3 * Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;

double newLat = Math.toDegrees(secondLatitude);
double newLng = Math.toDegrees(secondLongitude);
```

But what if I know coordinates of last location of whole path. How to control value of bearing to calculate location so that I have e.g. circle that starts and finishes in my current location?

Comment: This is not possible. imagine you have distance 100, 50. You cannot create bearings that lead back to your start, since there are only two lines and the second is half the length so it cannot reach the start point. And why the hack you want to do that?